# Get-CimInstance : Invalid namespace while installing Sitecore 9.1

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, installation

While running `.\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` at task 39 I am getting the error below:

> [-------------------------- XConnectXP0_RemoveServices [1] :
>   RemoveService -------------------------------------------]
>   Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Invalid namespace At
>   C:\ResourceFiles\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:74 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:54 Get-CimInstance : Invalid namespace At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-RemoveServiceTask.ps1:10
>   char:17
>   + ... $instance = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_service -Filter "Name = '$Na ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

I have Solr 7.2.1 up and running as a windows service. Don't understand what's causing this issue. Anyone had this before?

**Update:**
This is failing while running the below Json.

```
"RemoveServices": {
            "Description": "Removes the current service.",
            "Type": "RemoveService",
            "Params": [
                { "Name": "[variable('Services.IndexWorker.Name')]" },
                { "Name": "[variable('Services.MarketingAutomationEngine.Name')]" },
                { "Name": "[variable('Services.ProcessingEngine.Name')]" }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that you are missing the win32_service class in WMI for some reason. You should be able to repeat the error by running:
    `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service`

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/08/11/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class/

Seems to be good instructions on how to check and rebuild your WMI classes if needed.